# CoAP application development using openthread without using thread protocol

Tags: c++, c, coap, openthread

I want to use Openthread CoAP APIs and develop a CoAP client application(and a server as well later on). But I do not want to use the thread part of it. So I have following questions:

1. Is it possible that I disable the thread part in openthread and only build COAP/S at build time ?
2. Or, take the CoAP out of openthread and build it separately ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The CoAP client implementation is very minimal and is not intended to be used standalone. Have you considered busing libcoap instead? https://libcoap.net/

Comment: @jonathanberi Thank you for your response. Regarding using libcoap, yes I am considering this option as well, but only if it is not possible with Openthread. Because CoAP APIs in Openthread are quite user friendly as compared to others, I am willing to go with Openthread. While you say "very minimal", does it miss any critical feature (I am new to CoAP as well, so your guidance is much appreciated). I am aware that it does not have support of BLOCK TRANSFER at the moment. Is there anything else that I should be needing additionally ?

Comment: `> does it miss any critical feature`
That would depend on your application, CoAP is a rich specification and has several extensions, including blockwise transfer.

Besides features, you're going to pay overhead for using the OpenThread implementation, even if you disable parts of the Thread stack.